# Mongoose - accessing the version key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When saving an object using Mongoose, a version key property is assigned to the document.

According to the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#versionKey), the default value for the version key is `__v`

I am trying to access this version number property via the mongoose object using the following commands, but both calls return a value of `undefined`:

```
myObject.__v
myObject["__v"]
```

If I view the object directly via a logger then the property is visible and assigned a value. If I use `JSON.stringify( myObject )` then I can access the `__v` property using a regular expression.

More interestingly though, if I iterate through the keys of the object I see properties called `_version` and `__version` but no `__v` property.

Can anyone tell me how to access the `__v` property directly?

Comment: Have you tried `myObject.get('__v')`?

Comment: @Brett that works, thanks - stick it as an answer and I shall accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `myObject.get('__v')`.